# Linear algebra over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields, bilinear-form

Let $\mathbb{F}_p^3$ be a $3$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p$ odd. For any $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{F}_p^3$ define its "norm" $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2,$ where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

*Remark:* If $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{F}_p^3$ such that $\lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert=\lVert \mathbf{v}\rVert\neq 0$, then there exists $g\in SO_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $\mathbf{u}=g\mathbf{v}$. We note that $g$ is not unique, but we can achieve uniqueness by considering the quotient $O_3(\mathbb{F}_p)/O_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, i.e. there is a unique $O_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$-coset of elements $g$ with the property.

The last couple days I was trying to prove that remark but I failed. I was trying to construct such orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$ by hand but it did not work out. Can anyone provide the proof of that remark please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by $SO_3(\Bbb F_p)$. I would presume you're referring to matrices satisfying $A^TA = I$, but since this is not a standard context for the descriptor "orthogonal" I'd appreciate explicit clarification

Comment: @BenGrossmann, by $SO_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ I mean orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$ with entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: I forgot to mention the determinant constraint. But what does "orthogonal" mean in this context?

Comment: @BenGrossmann $A^TA=AA^T=I$ where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix with entries from $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, we consider a standard dot product.

Comment: Chiming in with Ben Grossmann. When moving to characteristic $p$ from the realm of real numbers sometimes (often!) $SO_n(k)$ preserves a quadratic form of a maximal Witt index rather than "the usual dot product". Anyway, a part of your problem may be that there is no unique copy of $O_2$ sitting inside $O_3$. You want the stabilizer of $v$ rather than some specific subgroup.

Comment: Funny things happen when $p=2$ (quadratic forms and characteristic two don't mesh too well). In that case there are exactly six $3\times3$ matrices $A$ such that $AA^T=I$, namely the permutation matrices. They all have $(1,1,1)^T$ as an eigenvector. Implying that the claim is false in that case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, of course we claim that $p\neq 2$

Comment: Ok. I edited the tags a bit. I hazard a guess that people familiar with group theory are better acquainted with the intricacies resulting from the choice of the preserved bilinear form as well as knowledge of how exactly this group acts on the vectors of square/non-square length, or even on the set zero length vectors.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, can you take a look at my recent post please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440870/order-of-group-of-orthogonal-matrices-over-finite-field